# Can't do anything about a folder despite having admin permissions

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I've got a folder c:\temp\nvidia.  It always says no permission whenever I try to modify this folder. Problem is even when I use the commandlie with admin privileges......I get the same message.

Is there anything how I can get rid of that folder?

Comment: Open 'Properties' - 'Security' - 'Advanced' - 'Change' window, make local Administrators built-in group the owner of this folder (including sub-objects). Apply, close and reopen properties window, then set the permissions which you need.

Comment: @Akina didn't work......from what I saw the "owner" has NO rights oO only system and a few applications have permissions

Comment: Use `psexec.exe`, start cmd.exe or explorer.exe using SYSTEM account, change owner and add permissions.

Comment: what is psexec?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec Use with caution... read description carefully. You need `-s -i` keys.

Comment: PS. Explorer cannot be executed using SYSTEM account. But you may use any alternative filemanager.